# Why is Riverpod StateNotifierProvider forgetting state?

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

RiverPod StateNotifierProvider is simply forgetting state. Has anyone experienced anything like the following?

THE SITUATION - have a page which contains a number of movie genres. On screen each genre is represented as a carousel where the user can swipe through the movies. The carousel sits within an Expandable Panel so the user can expand and collapse the genre to show or hide the carousel content. So far so good, this all works.

THE REQUIREMENT - I need a button on the page which can collapse or expand ALL items on the page.

To achieve this, i have a StateNotifierProvider… The state contains

A) [allGenresOnPage] The ID’s of all genres on the page (This list is passed to the StateNotifierProvider via the family argument)

B) [allFilteredGenres] The ID’s of all filtered genres (the ones the user has collapsed via screen interaction)

The notifier has a very simple method [toggleCollapseAll]… When the user ticks the collapse all toggle, i copy the content of [allGenresOnPage] into [allFilteredGenres], when they UN-tick the collapse toggle, it empties [allFilteredGenres]

THE PROBLEM - Is that my state is randomly FORGETTING the content of allGenresOnPage

I added print statement at the top of my [toggleCollapseAll] method which simply prints [allGenresOnPage] each time it is executed.

Here’s what is printed if i run the method 5 times in a row…

TAP 1 - “All GENRE IDs ON PAGE” [14, 878, 28, 12]”

TAP 2 - “All GENRE IDs ON PAGE” [14, 878, 28, 12]”

TAP 3 - “All GENRE IDs ON PAGE” [14, 878, 28, 12]”

TAP 4 - “All GENRE IDs ON PAGE” []”

TAP 5 - “All GENRE IDs ON PAGE” []”

… from here the content is forever lost

I really don't understand this… I don’t change the content of the state property ‘AllGenresOnPage’ via any method at any point! I can confirm that the provider only initializes once.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here?

This isn’t the first time i’ve had problems with riverpod. I had a similar problem a few months ago which resulted in me having to abandon riverpod and stateNotifier entirely… It seems to me provider simply can’t be trusted to retain state?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated - My full controller and provider is below incase it helps

```html
class ViewCarouselByGenreController
    extends StateNotifier<ViewCarouselByGenreState> {
  ViewCarouselByGenreController(
      this._localUserRepo, this._userService, this._genreKeys)
      : super(ViewCarouselByGenreState.initial()) {
    _init();
  }

  final List<String> _genreKeys;
  final LocalUserRepo _localUserRepo;
  final UserService _userService;

  void _init() async {
    final user = await _localUserRepo.fetchUserLocally();
    final filteredGenres = user.filteredGenreIds;
    state = state.copyWith(
      genreKeysOnPage: _genreKeys,
      filteredGenreKeys: filteredGenres,
    );
  }

  bool checkIfFiltered(String genreKey) {
    if (state.filteredGenreKeys.contains(genreKey)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // ! This stops looping because state.genreKeysOnPage randomly empties!
  bool? detectCollapseAllStatus() {
    int filteredCount = 0;
    for (final item in state.genreKeysOnPage) {
      if (state.filteredGenreKeys.contains(item)) {
        filteredCount++;
      }
    }
    if (filteredCount == state.genreKeysOnPage.length) {
      return true;
    } else if (filteredCount == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  void toggleCollapseAll() {
    final allGenreKeys = state.genreKeysOnPage;
    // ! This will be empty after from the 4th execution, Even if i pass _genreKeys directly 
    // ! (i.e the property received via family constructor) it still empties!!! 
    print('ALL GENRE KEYS: $allGenreKeys');
    final allCollapsed = detectCollapseAllStatus();
    if (allCollapsed == true) {
      state = state.copyWith(
        filteredGenreKeys: [],
        allGenresCollapsed: false,
      );
    } else {
      state = state.copyWith(
        filteredGenreKeys: allGenreKeys,
        allGenresCollapsed: true,
      );
    }
  }

  void toggleCollapseSingle(String filterKey) async {
    var filteredGenreKeys = state.filteredGenreKeys;
    if (filteredGenreKeys.contains(filterKey)) {
      filteredGenreKeys.removeWhere((element) => element == filterKey);
    } else {
      filteredGenreKeys.add(filterKey);
    }
    state = state.copyWith(filteredGenreKeys: filteredGenreKeys);
  }

  void saveFilterUpdates() {
    _userService.saveFilteredGenreUpdates(
        state.genreKeysOnPage, state.filteredGenreKeys);
  }
}

final viewCarouselByGenreControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<ViewCarouselByGenreController, ViewCarouselByGenreState,
        List<String>>(
  (ref, genreKeys) {
    return ViewCarouselByGenreController(
      ref.watch(localUserRepoProvider),
      ref.watch(userServiceProvider),
      genreKeys,
    );
  },
);
```

And here's my state class

```html
class ViewCarouselByGenreState {
  ViewCarouselByGenreState({
    this.allGenresCollapsed,
    required this.filteredGenreKeys,
    required this.genreKeysOnPage,
  });

  bool? allGenresCollapsed;
  List<String> filteredGenreKeys;
  List<String> genreKeysOnPage;

  factory ViewCarouselByGenreState.initial() {
    return ViewCarouselByGenreState(
      filteredGenreKeys: [],
      genreKeysOnPage: [],
    );
  }

  String get filteredKeysCommaSeparated =>
      filteredGenreKeys.map((e) => e).toList().join(', ');

  ViewCarouselByGenreState copyWith({
    bool? allGenresCollapsed,
    List<String>? filteredGenreKeys,
    List<String>? genreKeysOnPage,
  }) {
    return ViewCarouselByGenreState(
      allGenresCollapsed: allGenresCollapsed ?? this.allGenresCollapsed,
      filteredGenreKeys: filteredGenreKeys ?? this.filteredGenreKeys,
      genreKeysOnPage: genreKeysOnPage ?? this.genreKeysOnPage,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant ViewCarouselByGenreState other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other.allGenresCollapsed == allGenresCollapsed &&
        listEquals(other.filteredGenreKeys, filteredGenreKeys) &&
        listEquals(other.genreKeysOnPage, genreKeysOnPage);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      allGenresCollapsed.hashCode ^
      filteredGenreKeys.hashCode ^
      genreKeysOnPage.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'ViewCarouselByGenreState(allGenresCollapsed: $allGenresCollapsed, filteredGenreKeys: $filteredGenreKeys, genreKeysOnPage: $genreKeysOnPage)';
}
```

Comment: You have a family key of ViewCarouselByGenreState (if I'm reading this correctly).  You didn't include that class here.  Does it have a working == and hashCode?  As in, it must behave sensibly for equality.

Comment: Hi Randal, thanks for looking at this.

I have added the state class which is managed by the stateNotifier above. It's incredibly simple with just a nullable bool and two lists of strings. I used the Dart Data Class Generator to generate the equality code so it should certainly be sensible.